# Flask Pycharm css files is permanently attached to html

Tags: html, css, flask, pycharm

I'm working in PyCharm, using Flask.

I have one html file and one css file. I wrote all the code, launched and everything was fine, but for some reason when I am making css file changes those changes don't show up. I can even delete the css file and the design will still be the same. What I am doing wrong?

I have debug mode on, tried rerun, stop/start, even restarting Pycharm. When I am changing the html file everything changes like it is suppose to.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Then [edit] the question to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use PyCharm, but when I work on my Flask apps and make CSS changes I make sure to *force reload* my browser. This will fully refresh the page and CSS changes will be reflected.

For *force reload* of web browsers (generally speaking):
Windows: ctrl + F5
Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
Linux: F5

PyCharm caches all project files. If you don't mind deleting the *entire PyCharm cache* you might try that. First I would try checking out your changes in the browser with a force reload.